# bigquery syntax- to count rows which are common between 2 tables

Tags: google-bigquery

How to count common rows between 2 tables in big-query? 
What is the syntax?

Example-

```
SELECT *
FROM table A
INNER JOIN table B
```

The code does not work that is on w3schools?

Comment: can you show us the code that doesn't work?

Comment: The example provided does not looks like counting common rows between 2 tables, can you confirm if you provided the correct example?